# How to draw a 3D line in PySide6 using Qt3D module

Tags: python, 3d, pyside6, pyqt6, qt6

I have been struggling with drawing primitive lines inside a Qt3D module in Qt6/PySide6.
The only guide I have found was in this old question: [How do I draw a simple line in Qt3D?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067867/how-do-i-draw-a-simple-line-in-qt3d), but when I rewrote the code from Qt5 in C++ to PySide6 the window was empty and no 3D lines had rendered.

My goal is to show a path of an moving object in a 3D space. I also want to be able to add points to the path even after initialization since I have endless stream of data from an IMU.

I also get two warnings when run:

1. Qt3D.Renderer.RHI.Backend: Initializing RHI with DirectX backend
2. findBoundingVolumeComputeData: Position attribute not suited for bounding volume computation

Update: I have found another post: [setVertexCount API of QGeometryRenderer and its effect on ray casting results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60913389/setvertexcount-api-of-qgeometryrenderer-and-its-effect-on-ray-casting-results), but that didn't help either.

I have tested that the attributes vanish from geometry after the `__init__()`, but assigning them to `self` crashes the program for reaching unauthorized part of memory.

My code:

```
from PySide6.QtCore import QTimer, QByteArray
from PySide6.QtGui import QVector3D, QColor
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget
from PySide6.Qt3DCore import Qt3DCore
from PySide6.Qt3DExtras import Qt3DExtras
from PySide6.Qt3DRender import Qt3DRender
import struct

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Set up the 3D view
        self.view = Qt3DExtras.Qt3DWindow()
        self.view.defaultFrameGraph().setClearColor(QColor(255,255,255))
        self.container = QWidget.createWindowContainer(self.view)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.container)

        # Set up the 3D scene
        self.root = Qt3DCore.QEntity()
        self.view.setRootEntity(self.root)
        # Create a 3D entity for the line
        self.line_entity = Qt3DCore.QEntity(self.root)
        line_geometry = Qt3DCore.QGeometry(self.line_entity)

        # Create a custom line geometry
        vertex_data = [QVector3D(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), QVector3D(1.0, 0.0, 0.0), QVector3D(1.0, 1.0, 0.0)]
        vertex_byteArray = QByteArray()

        for vector in vertex_data:
            vertex_byteArray.append(struct.pack('fff', vector.x(), vector.y(), vector.z()))

        vertex_buffer = Qt3DCore.QBuffer(line_geometry)
        vertex_buffer.setData(vertex_byteArray)

        # Create a QAttribute to store the vertex data
        vertex_attribute = Qt3DCore.QAttribute()
        vertex_attribute.setName(Qt3DCore.QAttribute.defaultPositionAttributeName())
        vertex_attribute.setAttributeType(Qt3DCore.QAttribute.AttributeType.VertexAttribute)
        vertex_attribute.setVertexBaseType(Qt3DCore.QAttribute.VertexBaseType.Float)
        vertex_attribute.setBuffer(vertex_buffer)
        vertex_attribute.setVertexSize(3)  # 3 components (X, Y, Z) per vertex
        vertex_attribute.setByteOffset(0)
        vertex_attribute.setByteStride(3 * 4)  # 3 components * 4 bytes for float
        vertex_attribute.setCount(len(vertex_data))

        line_geometry.addAttribute(vertex_attribute)

        # Create connections between vertices
        index_data = [0,1,2]
        index_bytes = QByteArray()
        index_bytes.append(bytearray(index_data))

        index_buffer = Qt3DCore.QBuffer(line_geometry)
        index_buffer.setData(index_bytes)

        # Create a QAttribute to store the index data
        index_attribute = Qt3DCore.QAttribute()
        # index_attribute.setName(Qt3DCore.QAttribute.defaultJointIndicesAttributeName())
        index_attribute.setAttributeType(Qt3DCore.QAttribute.AttributeType.IndexAttribute)
        index_attribute.setVertexBaseType(Qt3DCore.QAttribute.VertexBaseType.UnsignedInt)
        index_attribute.setBuffer(index_buffer)
        index_attribute.setCount(len(index_data))

        line_geometry.addAttribute(index_attribute)

        # Create a line material
        self.line_material = Qt3DExtras.QPhongMaterial(self.root)
        self.line_material.setAmbient(QColor(255,0,0))

        # Create a line renderer
        self.line_renderer = Qt3DRender.QGeometryRenderer(self.root)
        self.line_renderer.setPrimitiveType(Qt3DRender.QGeometryRenderer.LineStrip)
        self.line_renderer.setGeometry(line_geometry)
        self.line_renderer.setVertexCount(len(vertex_data))

        self.line_entity.addComponent(self.line_renderer)
        self.line_entity.addComponent(self.line_material)

        # Set up camera
        self.camera_entity = self.view.camera()
        # camera_entity.lens().setPerspectiveProjection(45.0, 16.0/9.0, 0.1, 1000.0)
        self.camera_entity.setPosition(QVector3D(2, 2, 5))
        self.camera_entity.setViewCenter(QVector3D(0, 0, 0))

        # Set up orbit controller
        self.orbit_controller = Qt3DExtras.QOrbitCameraController(self.root)
        self.orbit_controller.setLinearSpeed(2.0)
        self.orbit_controller.setLookSpeed(100.0)
        self.orbit_controller.setCamera(self.camera_entity)

        # Add vertices after a delay
        QTimer.singleShot(2000, self.add_more_vertices)

        self.show()

    def add_more_vertices(self):
        new_vertices = [QVector3D(1.2, 1.2, 1.2), QVector3D(1.5, 1.5, 1.5), QVector3D(1.8, 1.8, 1.8)]



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication()
    window = MainWindow()
    app.exec()
```

Comment: I don't have nor have ever used the Qt3D module, so I am just going with a hunch. I see a lot of local variables and just a few persistent objects. In fact, the only *explicit* persistent object related to the 3D stuff is `self.view`, and the only relation with all that is the `camera_entity` and the `setCamera()` call (which doesn't seem to provide any persistence nor set any ownership). For what I can see, almost anything that is not set as a member of `self` will become garbage collected as soon as `__init__` returns. At least try to make `root` and `orbit_controller` attributes of `self`.

Comment: Thanks @musicamante for suggestion. I have edited the code and it caused a second warning to show up, so I think you were right, but the problem wasn't resolved.